# Can't turn off require_no_authentication in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm aware that there are already a few Stack overflow q&a's regarding this, but they have not helped solve my issue.

I have a custom user registrations controller that inherits from devise registrations controller, i.e.:

```
class UsersController < Devise::RegistrationsController
```

I want to disable the authentication filter in the devise registrations controller. i.e disable this line:

```
class Devise::RegistrationsController < DeviseController
    prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, only: [ :new, :create, :cancel ]
```

so that no authentication is required to edit a user.

Other stack overflow answers have suggested skipping the filter in the custom controller, i.e.

```
class UsersController < Devise::RegistrationsController
   skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication
end
```

but this does not work for me. When I attempt to edit a user, a page is displayed saying:

```
you need to sign in or sign up before continuing.
```

I don't think my routing is an issue. My routes are:

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions, :registrations, :passwords]

devise_scope :user do
    resources :user
end
```

Thanks and much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You were looking for something like this:

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:edit]
```

The before filter you are disabling is not used to skip authorization. It is used to check if an existing valid session already exists. This is hinted at in the last few lines by the redirect and message. This is handy to disable if want users to be able to switch sessions without signing out or as a security measure to keep old sessions from being restored which was my use case.

```
  # Helper for use in before_actions where no authentication is required.
  #
  # Example:
  #   before_action :require_no_authentication, only: :new
  def require_no_authentication
    assert_is_devise_resource!
    return unless is_navigational_format?
    no_input = devise_mapping.no_input_strategies

    authenticated = if no_input.present?
      args = no_input.dup.push scope: resource_name
      warden.authenticate?(*args)
    else
      warden.authenticated?(resource_name)
    end

    if authenticated && resource = warden.user(resource_name)
      flash[:alert] = I18n.t("devise.failure.already_authenticated")
      redirect_to after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score -1):

applying the following:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  skip_before_action :require_no_authentication
end
```